# How to find the size of a webpage in windows phone 8

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I need to know the size of a webpage before it is loaded in the windows phone to indicate the percentage of the webpage that has been loaded.

Comment: What did you try so far? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179035/how-does-proof-of-effort-make-a-question-better

Comment: I didn't try anything so far..